Softball question on force play at 3rd, bases loaded, 1 out
Bases loaded, ball is hit to 3rd baseman. The runner on 3rd did not run towards home(even though she has too). 3rd baseman steps on bag to force the person running from second to be out, also tags person still standing on bag because she didn't run. Is this a double play?

From the USA Softball rules definitions:

FORCE OUT: An out which may be made only when a runner loses the right
to the base that the runner is occupying because the batter becomes a
batter-runner, and before the batter-runner or a trailing runner has
been put out.

Although R3 no longer has the right to the base after the ball is put in play, that runner was not put out by tagging home plate or the runner.
By tagging third base, R2 is put out.   This allows the trailing runner part of the rule to be in effect.  R3 can no longer be forced out.
Looking at Rule 8, Section 7, none of the conditions for a runner being out are met on R3.   Part C is not applicable since a trailing runner has been put out.
There is no double play.

Although there would have been a double play if the runner standing on 3rd was tagged before stepping on the bag - i.e. the 3rd baseman messed up.
